# Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) выдает ошибку даже на пустой html файл

Tags: html, pagespeed-insights

Подскажите на что конкретно гугл ругается?

Файл абсолютно пустой, нет css, нет js, нет картинок, и нет абсолютно никакого смещения контента, ничего внешнего не подключается[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас присутствует meta viewport тег в head?

Comment: @highpassion да `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`

Comment: интересно, не указано что влияет на этот показатель в подробном отчете?

Comment: @highpassion там все пусто

Comment: это отчет за 28 дней, у вас показатель lab data - CLS - 0

Comment: @highpassion подскажите пожалуйста что означает за 28 дней, то есть он уже никогда не изменится? Получится его как то изменить?

Comment: это значит, что Lighthouse собирает данные за последние 28 дней, каждый день будет новая инфа